# Create custom functions in Excel (Preview)

Tags: excel, ms-office, office365, office-js, custom-functions-excel

We have Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus Subscription. 
Version 1806(Build 10228.20021 Click-to-Run)
Monthly Channel(Targeted). 
I have downloaded the Custom Function sample from https://github.com/OfficeDev/Excel-Custom-Functions and deployed that in my IIS. I have changed the local host accordingly in all four places. Created the manifest file .I have shared that manifest to my name. Now am able to see the "Custom Functions Sample" in Office Add-ins SHARED FOLDER but when i try to type =Contoso in my excel the custom function is not coming. Need Help on this.

Comment: When you see the add-in in SHARED FOLDER, do you then select it and press Add?

Comment: Hi Rick, Yes I have added that and I can see pane at the right side with the details. But I can’t see contoso if I type =contoso. Also another information I have office 365 Enterprise E3.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you have to sign up for the Insiders program (https://products.office.com/en-us/office-insider?tab=Windows-Desktop) which appears to be something of a beta program. You run pre-release versions of office - these have the custom functions capability. You'll probably want to do this in a virtual machine if your dev machine is used to build/test production add-ins,